# Split the full contents of cell between UILabel and UIButton

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a subclassed UITableViewCell. I'm dynamically adding a UILabel and UIButton to it.

Right now I've overridden layoutSubviews and am setting the x,y absolutely of the button and label. To be able to accommodate both screen layouts as well as larger screens I'd like to make this automatic.  Is there a way to tell the label to "float left" and the button to "float right?" Ideally the label should use up all space that the button doesn't need (the button is going to be a fixed size for the most part).

Answer (score 0):

[this property of uiview should get you started](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this assuming cellLbl is the UILabel and cellBtn is the UIButton:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
  CGRect rctFrm;
  CGFloat flW;
  CGFloat flH;
  int iSpacing = 4; // This could be fixed for a percentage of cell width

  [super layoutSubviews];
  flW = self.contentView.bounds.size.width;
  flH = self.contentView.bounds.size.height;
  rctFrm = self.cellBtn.frame;
  flW -= rctFrm.size.width + iSpacing;
  rctFrm.origin.x = flW; // Right justify button
  rctFrm.origin.y = (flH - rctFrm.size.height) / 2; // Center button vertically
  [self.cellBtn setFrame:rctFrm];
  rctFrm = self.cellLbl.frame;
  rctFrm.origin.x = iSpacing;
  rctFrm.size.width = flW - (2 * iSpacing);
  // You can adjust UILabel vertical position and height if desired
  [self.cellLbl setFrame:rctFrm];
}
```